# Is there a benefit to disabling Jenkins projects/jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

Just looking for input on this one, but is there any benefit for disabling or deleting jobs?

Does disabling a job force the slave/node to remove any workspaces for that job or does disabling a job change how much the master has to work through?

TIA for any feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling a job is useful when it is a scheduled job, or one triggered by a hook

Few cases it could be of interest to disable a job:

- You are aware of a third party service causing issues and you do not want your job to partially execute and fail, you could disable it the time the issue gets resolved by the team in charge of the 3rd party service.
- Or someone in your team wants to make a demo on a server that gets updated by jenkins and would like the server not to be redeployed during the demo
- You are working on a job that is not finally done, you have an urgency and want to disable the job until you can get back to working on it

Finally, in my opinion, if you only have pipeline jobs generated by a Jenkinsfile for each projects. You won't need to disable a job ever

Comment: This is a great answer. In addition to this, I found another good reason to disable jobs. On most of the jobs being disabled, they are scheduled to check our source control manager for updates. Several were configured with * * * * *, so this means they were checking for updates every minute, of every day, equaling 1440 times per day. In essence, disabling jobs can help to lighten the load of the master running scheduled checks.

Comment: nice addition @ScottTee, also note that if you are using jobDSL, you might have jobs disabled. These jobs will come back as enabled when they are generated again. I made a library that dynamically solves this issue. The code is there https://github.com/sap-archive/jenkins-pipelayer/tree/master/vars/generateJobs.groovy#L31

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no real benefit for disabling or deleting jobs. Up until now, I only see one benefit when you put Jenkins jobs in a pipeline, so you can test each upstream job without trigger downstream job mistakenly. 
Disabling a job doesn't remove any workspaces on the slave/node and doesn't influence how much the master has to work through.